# Document with tracking and without tracking

Tags: two-column, letters, journal-publishing, latexdiff

I have created the latex paper for the submission in IEEE letters. The letter is two column single space. In order to submit the revision i need to make three documents:
a) single-column double-space version with track changes.
b-c) double-column single-space and single-column double-space formats without tracking the changes.

Anyone please tell me how can make these documents with tracking and without?
I can do tracking  using the `latexdiff`. is there any way i can also remove the blue line under the text.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, or you are asking more than one question. Presumably the information on the IEEE template tells you how to make single and double space documents. And for removing the blue line just edit the \DIFadd command definition in the latex file resulting from the latexdiff run

Comment: IEEEtran provides three draft modes: draft, draftcls and draftclsnofoot (plus final).  Hopefully these will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @frederik What to edit in \DIFadd command definition? currently its like that: \providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}}

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have tried draftclsnofoot, It makes the document single column but does it makes double spacing? Also what draft and draftcls means

Comment: According to the manual, (page 2), all the draft modes double the line spacing (so in practice, yes).

Comment: Just delete `\uwave` and new text will be blue but not underlined.  Or use option `-t CFONT` when running latexdiff for a non-underlining markup style.